# Override object creation with same class in another namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I'm trying to trick PHP into taking a class from another namespace when trying to create a specific class.

I have two class called "page", the first is in the Core namespace:

```
namespace Core;
class Page {...}
```

The second inherits from Core\Page, but adds a few things. It is in the Addons namespace.

```
namespace Addons;
class Page extends \Core\Page{...}
```

The reason I want to do this is because I want to build my system with an easy addon engine. Whenever I want, I can add a line in an XML file that tells the autoloading function to take the class in the addon namespace instead of the core namespace.

However, when I try to do this :

```
spl_autoload_register('loadClass');

public function loadClass(string $className)
{
    if (Addon_exist_and_is_registered($className))
    {
        require "/Addons/$className.php";
    }
    else
    {
        require "/Core/$className.php";
    }
}

$page = new \Core\Page(); <-- error here
```

I get an error saying that the class \Core\Page cannot be found in the file Addons\Page.php. This is normal behaviour since the class is not in the same namespace and as such, the fully qualified name cannot find the right class.

Is it possible to trick PHP into thinking that a child class in another namespace is actually the right class? I tried this for the addons class;

```
namespace Core;
class Page extends \Core\Page{...}
```

But it breaks the inheritance as you cannot inherit yourself.

Comment: The problem is you have to include **both** classes to make the `Addons\Page` work. There is no way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore that the classes have the "same name". Because they don't. One class is called `Core\Page`, the other is called `Addons\Page`. **Those are their names**, their *fully qualified* names to be exact. It's as much a difference as `Foo` and `Bar`. If you tell PHP to instantiate `Core\Page`, then it's going to do that; you can't "trick" it into instantiating `Addons\Page`, since that's an entirely different class name.

Don't try to "trick" anyone, make your system actually extensible and explicitly allow overriding of class names:

```
$class = 'Core\Page';
if (...) {
    $class = 'Addons\Page';
}

$page = new $class;
```

Comment: The things is, I want my system to be unaware of the addon's existence, this is why I use the Autoloader. For example, If I create a page object in the route class, I don't, want my route class to have 10 if for all possible addons over page.

Comment: It's simply not possible. You could *replace* a class outright by creating another `Core\Page` class in your addon and load that instead. But then it's impossible to `extend` the existing `Core\Page` class, because you'd have to load it in order to `extend` it, but if you do that you can't replace it anymore (`Class already defined` error). It's also a terrible idea from a maintenance standpoint to slyly exchange implementations "behind PHP's back", it's just going to lead to a lot of headaches. **Make your system explicitly extensible.**

Comment: Okay thanks, your confirmed what I feared. Would it be a good idea to build an object factory that builds all objects for the core and is tasked with checking if an addon exists? It seems a bit counter intuitive to have  to write objectfactory::create("Core\Page"); instead of new Core\page(); Do you have a better idea?

Comment: In the end that's what you have to do. You want to be able to do it both ways: instantiate `Core\Page` if you explicitly want to, but also conditionally instantiate some overridden class. I can't stress this enough: **you want to be explicit about which is going to happen.** `new Core\Page` should always instantiate `Core\Page`. `$dependencyContainer->getPageInstance()` should conditionally get the current applicable class. You're only going to shoot yourself in the foot sooner or later if `new Core\Page` would instantiate something other than `Core\Page`.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks. It'll break the intelicence, but that's to be expected with PHP anyway.